# Weierstrass elliptic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am wondering about Weierstrass elipctic function. Let's order the points on the lattice and denote them $\omega_n$, $n=1,2,\dots$

If I wanted a meromorphic function with poles at $w_n$ and $0$, whose principal part is $\frac{1}{z^2}$ around zero and $\frac{1}{(z-w_n)^2}$ around $w_n$, could I use the following function?

$$\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z-w_n)^2}$$

Or I would have to use in fact Weierstrass function:

$$\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{(z-w_n)^2}-\frac{1}{w_n^2}]$$

So I guess my question is why do we substract this $\frac{1}{w_n^2}$. Is the first series not convergent?

Comment: Indeed the first series is not absolutely convergent.